# Core request handler documentation maybe has conflicting information?

Tags: 8

I wanted to confirm with the community and maybe get some clarity about D8 Documentation:

On the [Core request handling system ported to Symfony2 framework](https://www.drupal.org/node/1635626) page it states:

> The PHP superglobals for $_GET, $_POST, and $_SERVER are deprecated
>   and should not be used, ever.

However, I can't seem to locate this information on php.net. PHP setting register_globals is deprecated. Is this what they are refering to or did I miss something huge in recent news? No longer able to use $_GET in our custom modules for D8?

Comment: Use the `RequestStack` service.

Comment: Yes, because Drupal is a stack middleware, see https://stackphp.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the advice stems from this issue: [Replace almost all remaining superglobals ($_GET, $_POST, etc.) with Symfony Request object](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1998638). The opening gambit from that post is:

> In order to depend on using the Request object to determine caching, we need to ensure that everything uses it, rather than raw PHP variables for $_SERVER, $_REQUEST, $_GET, $_POST.

I don't the quoted comment is suggesting they're deprecated in PHP as such, just that using them in Drupal isn't going to be reliable.